# Localize combobox items in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, combobox, localization

I am working on a localized windows form application.

On the form, I have set the property "Localizable" to True, and I have added the localized translations of my controls. So far all works fine.

But I also have a 20+ comboboxes on my form, and ideally I would like to localize the **contents** of these comboboxes too.

I want to give the user the option to change the language at run-time, by selecting a different language from a combobox. Therefore I have created two DataTables, one holding the "language" and one holding all the tranlations of the combobox items.

Here's the code I have written:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim myLanguages As New DataTable("cboLanguage")
Dim myDataTable As New DataTable("cboTest")

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    myLanguages.Columns.Add("Language")
    myLanguages.Columns.Add("Code")

    myLanguages.Rows.Add("English", "en")
    myLanguages.Rows.Add("Nederlands", "nl")
    myLanguages.Rows.Add("Deutsch", "de")
    myLanguages.Rows.Add("Francais", "fr")

    myDataTable.Columns.Add("id", System.Type.GetType("System.Int16"))
    myDataTable.Columns.Add("en", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    myDataTable.Columns.Add("nl", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    myDataTable.Columns.Add("de", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    myDataTable.Columns.Add("fr", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))

    myDataTable.Rows.Add(1, "One", "Een", "Eins", "Un")
    myDataTable.Rows.Add(2, "Two", "Twee", "Twei", "Deux")
    myDataTable.Rows.Add(3, "Three", "Drie", "Drei", "Trois")
    myDataTable.Rows.Add(4, "Four", "Vier", "Vier", "Quatre")

    cboTest.DataSource = myDataTable
    cboTest.ValueMember = "id"
    'cboTest.DisplayMember is being set by the cboLanguage_SelectedIndexChanged

    cboLanguage.DataSource = myLanguages
    cboLanguage.ValueMember = "Code"
    cboLanguage.DisplayMember = "Language"

    cboLanguage.SelectedIndex = 0
End Sub

Private Sub cboLanguage_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cboLanguage.SelectedIndexChanged
    If cboLanguage.SelectedIndex < 0 Then Exit Sub

    cboTest.DisplayMember = cboLanguage.SelectedValue.ToString
End Sub

Private Sub cboTest_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cboTest.SelectedIndexChanged
    If cboTest.SelectedIndex < 0 Then Exit Sub

    MsgBox(cboTest.SelectedValue.ToString)
End Sub
End Class
```

The form has two comboboxes ("cboLanguage" and "cboTest").

Running this code triggers the "cboTest_SelectedIndexChanged" twice when the form is Loading. Changing the langues will also trigger the "cboTest_SelectedIndexChanged", but the SelectedIndex remains the same (which is good, I don't want the combobox to "reset" when a user is changing the language).

This is just a small example, but like I said, I have 20+ comboboxes on my real form.

Should I implement this for 20+ comboboxes?
Are there any alternative ways?

Is there a best practice when dealing with localizing combobox items?

=bump=

Comment: I would keep my Localized strings in the resource file. You build up the combobox by doing a `GetString(String.Format("{0}_{1}", cboTest.Name, id));` for each row where id is the key of the row in that table. So you have in the resource file an entry for 'cboTest_1' with value 'One' for english, 'Een' voor Nederlands, 'Eins' für Deutsch and 'Une' pour Francais.

Comment: @rene, thanks for the suggestion. If there're other methods, I would love to hear them!